# How to get count from groupby operation into new column with Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to count all unique barcodes (2 in this case)  in this groupby operation. Then I would like to write the count value into a new column into my dataframe. I am banging my head against the wall, trying all kinds of things without success so far. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
parcelno        barcode         product
01565115935496  1234567890123   DPD CLASSIC NP (Europa)  count                 1
                                                         unique                1
                                                         top       1234567890123
                                                         freq                  1
                                Dieselzuschlag           count                 1
                                                         unique                1
                                                         top       1234567890123
                                                         freq                  1
                                Maut                     count                 1
                                                         unique                1
                                                         top       1234567890123
                                                         freq                  1
                                Sicherheitsgebuhr        count                 1
                                                         unique                1
                                                         top       1234567890123
                                                         freq                  1
                                Verzollungsabwicklung    count                 1
                                                         unique                1
                                                         top       1234567890123
                                                         freq                  1
                0987654321097   DPD CLASSIC NP (Europa)  count                 1
                                                         unique                1
                                                         top       0987654321097
                                                         freq                  1
                                Dieselzuschlag           count                 1
                                                         unique                1
                                                         top       0987654321097
                                                         freq                  1
                                Maut                     count                 1
                                                         unique                1
                                                         top       0987654321097
                                                         freq                  1
                                Sicherheitsgebuhr        count                 1
                                                         unique                1
                                                         top       0987654321097
                                                         freq                  1
                                Verzollungsabwicklung    count                 1
                                                         unique                1
                                                         top       0987654321097
                                                         freq                  1
```

Comment: Can't you just do : `len(set(df['barcode'])` (if your dataframe is called `df`)?

Comment: I have multiple transactions (parcelno's) so I believe that it will be required to use groupby?

Comment: `len(set(df.groupby('parcelno')['barcode'])` I can't check but this could do the trick. Let me know if not

Answer (score 0):

You can count unique column values in any pandas dataframe using:

```
dataframe.column_name.unique()
```

In your case, it would be

```
df.barcode.unique()
```

or

```
 df["barcode"].unique()
```

where df is the dataframe and barcode is the column.

Answer (score 0):

What you've displayed is a `pd.Series`.  I've duplicated it with this setup

***setup***

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
        ['01565115935496'],
        ['1234567890123', '0987654321097'],
        ['DPD CLASSIC NP (Europa)', 'Dieselzuschlag', 'Maut', 'Sicherheitsgebuhr', 'Verzollungsabwicklung'],
        ['count', 'unique', 'top', 'freq']
    ], names=['parcelno', 'barcode', 'product', None])

s = pd.Series([1, 1, '1234567890123', 1] * 5 + [1, 1, '0987654321097', 1] * 5, mux)
```

---

***number of unique barcodes***
Notice that `'barcode'` is the second level of the `pd.Series` multiiindex.

```
s.index.levels[1].nunique()

2
```

***`'count'` in its own column***

```
s.unstack()
```

[image]